# permission denied creating directories as non-root in docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a script which must be run as a non-root. This script also creates directories and files. If I run the script as a non-root user in docker, I get a permission denied error creating dirs. I tried to chmod the parent directory the script is in but it doesn't work. What should be the best practice here?

```
RUN mkdir test
WORKDIR /test
USER testuser
RUN mkdir .cache     <--- permission denied
```

Comment: I'd typically recommend doing as much work as you can as root in the Dockerfile, and switch to a non-root user only at the end.  Most files should be owned by root and non-writeable.  Limit the writeable state to a single directory, stored somewhere separate from your application code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That happens because your /test directory was created by root, and by default won't allow any other users to create anything in it. To change ownership to the user you want, you can use `chown` before your `USER testuser` step:

```
RUN chown testuser /test
```

If there are already files inside the directory, you will need to pass the `-R` flag to change the permission recursively:

```
RUN chown -R testuser /test
```

Another option would be giving the directory red+write+execute permissions for all users. However, this is probably NOT what you want, the above should serve you well for almost all cases.

```
RUN chmod 777 /test
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I did try a chown test before switching workdir.. didnt work tho

Comment: how did it not work? Does the user "usertest" exist?

Comment: yeah I have a `adduser testuser` before chown

Comment: do you have anything inside /test already? If so, you need to pass `-R` to `chown` for it to be recursive.